# fractional undifferencing - forecasting with ARFIMA

Tags: r, arfima

Suppose I have a time-series data which I want to apply ARFIMA model to. I want to calculate the parameters automatically, as it is done in `auto.arima` function. What I figured out so far is to find the order of fractional differentiation `d`, differentiate the time series using `d`, then apply `auto.arima` and make forecast.

Here's the code I'd go with:

```
d <- fdGPH(ts_data)
ts_diff <- diffseries(ts_data, d = d)
fit <- auto.arima(ts_diff)
fc <- forecast(fit , h = 96)
```

The problem is that my forecast is related to differentiated data, not the original one. Is there way to 'undifferentiate' the series (fractionally) as the differentiation here means the expansion to binomial series?
I know that there is function `arfima` in forecast package where author claims that it combines `fracdiff` and `auto.arima` package, but in my case it gives no sensible result - the forecast is almost constant.